# How do I create a simple history tracker in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Looking for a way to keep track of clicks in JavaScript. I have a series of javascript controlled sides in separate div wrapppers. I'll need a counter that will keep track of the previous slide number that was clicked. This will be used to fade out the previous div when the new div loads. The HTML page will not reload so I don't think I can use the browser history function as an option. I really only need to know the previous slide number since the slide numbers can be clicked out order.

Comment: are you using jQuery?  Any slider plugins from any framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable and update it everytime when there has been clicked on a new slide, but I think it's easier to just fade out all the slides, then fade in the slide that was clicked on.

This way you don't need to know which slide is currently shown.

Léon

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the user to never reload the page, then what is keeping you from simply using a regular JavaScript variable?

```
var currentSlideIndex = 0;
function nextSlide() {
  currentSlide = currentSlide + 1;
  if (currentSlide >= slideCount) {
    currentSlide = 0;
  }
}
```

You'll find that many similar HTML5-slide packages, keep track of the current slide in the document fragment identifier of the browser. When you do that, the slideshow can survive an F5 and users can send links to the current slide by copy/pasting the address.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/), but it's a bit of overkill.  The bonus is that it's semantic, and will keep the state on browser reload.  Also the back button goes to the previous tab.

Other solutions depend on your setup, and your libraries that are available (jQuery, etc.).  If you're using a standard plugin for something, they usually have callbacks for when the state changes.  Check the API.

The basic algorithm is applying a click handler to each button.  You can store a global variable containing the current state.  Give a class like `.slideButtons` to the absolute buttons (page1, page2, page3, etc.) and a id of `#nextSlide` and `#prevSlide` to the next and previous buttons selectively.  In the handler, check the class and id.  If it's nextSlide, or prevSlide, add one, or subtract one, and then update.  If it's one of the absolute ones, search in the parent node and count the matching classes until you find the one you're looking for.  The number of your counter when you reach your pressed button is the new state.  Set it, and update the slider.